# Error on OR on filter Django

Tags: django, filter, orm

i'm try create or on filter on django

**This is my little example :**

```
products=Products.objects.values('name', 'price').all().filter(status=1|0)
```

The problem is that don't validate the two options **(1|0)**
don't get a error on the print(products.query) only validate one option don't the 2 options..!!

Please thanks !!

Comment: `all().filter()` is redundant

Comment: why ?  maybe you can expĺain me  this .. thanks !!

Comment: check [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50299287/5644965) below, I explained

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To filter using **OR** in django you need a special class called `Q`.
[Documentation about Complex lookups with Q objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

```
from django.db.models import Q

products = Products.objects.values('name', 'price').filter(Q(status=1) | Q(status=0))
```

Answer (score 1):

It's good to use [`Q`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) object

```
manager.filter(Q(status=1) | Q(status=0))
```

You need to know that the method `all()` on a manager just delegates to `get_queryset()`.
To use `filter()`, you would already have the `QuerySet`

Rather than `all()` whose calls the *queryset*, and then `filter` whose already call the queryset,
just do `manager.filter()`

#### `all().filter()` becomes just `filter()` because it's redundant

There it is:

```
from django.db.models import Q

products = Product.objects.values('name','price').filter(
                 Q(status=1) | Q(status=0),
           )
```

Comment: oh, thanks, I think that i need to read more the documentation